# SSAS Cube Only Displays Total Values

Tags: ssas, facttable, cube, dimension

When browsing my cube it shows the correct invoice values by date when I select only a date type (the date table was generated by SSAS with hierarchies), but if I add the customer name it shows the combined value of the invoices for the date period, rather than the total per customer. I expect to see the total value for the customer that month, not the overall monthly total.

[image: Excel Example]

My tables are joined with foreign keys and the DSV shows a star schema. A simplified version of the schema is below.

```
factInvoice
invoicePK
customerFK -> customerPK
dateFK -> datePK

dimDate
datePK

dimCustomer
customerPK
```

The dimension usage tab shows both dimensions are linked to the invoice table.

[image: dimension usage tab]

Please can somebody shed some light on why this is happening? I'm sure I'm missing something pretty basic here! Thanks.

Comment: "if I add the customer name it shows the combined value of the invoices for the date period, rather than the total per customer." I'm not sure I follow. A screenshot would help.

Comment: @GregGalloway sure I have added an image. Hopefully that explains it better. I expect to see the total value for each customer that month, not the overall monthly total. Thanks for looking.

Comment: still don't follow. Give me a specific example. What do you expect to see for January for Company A and how should it be calculated.

Comment: @GregGalloway I expect to see their total sales for that month. Currently it is showing the total for company A + company B + company C etc etc in each month. So for example company A = 1000, company B = 500 and the rest of the company totals would add up to 5000. Thanks.

Comment: got it. Can you screenshot the Dimension Usage tab? Is it all regular measures? Any calculated measures?

Comment: @GregGalloway I've added the image. No calculated measures. Its the most basic of configurations as far as I am aware. Thanks again.

Comment: I bet I know what's going on. The Invoice measure group is joined to the Customer dimension not at the key attribute but some other attribute. Is that correct? That would explain the repeating data.

Comment: @GregGalloway spot on! I was going through a tutorial which recommended using a surrogate key for dimensions in case the key changed, such as using a new client management system which assigns a new client id. Was that an incorrect approach or did I misunderstand?

Comment: surrogate keys are recommended. For example if you have two CRM systems both with a Customer number 100 then it may be difficult to use natural keys. And sometimes you need Slowly Changing Dimensions to properly represent history which requires a surrogate key. Even Date dimensions should use an integer surrogate key because that gives you flexibility to setup a -1 key which means Unknown and a -2 key which means "before the beginning of the date dimension" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Customer dimension is joined to the measure group at a non-key granularity. If the Customer Name attribute isn't related to the attribute you join on then data repeats in reports. You need to do one of two things:

1. Recommended. Change the fact table to have the surrogate key of the dimension. Then change the Dimension Usage tab to join to the key of the dimension.
2. Change the dimension to change which column is used as the key of the dimension. Make sure the fact table has this column. Fix the Dimension Usage tab to join to the dimension key.

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure I understand... During SSIS import of the invoice data I should lookup the surrogate key in the customer dimension and add that to the invoice fact table?

Comment: @scampbell right. Not required (since you could do #2) but recommended